# How to join 2 tables incase join parameter is array?

Tags: mysql

How to join 2 tables in the following case? Case is so complicate, I am not sure how to ask.
Anyway that is my 2 tables. Please have a look.

> This is album_tb

[image]

> This is cart_tb

[image]

In "cart_tb", I want to add "album_images" field within album images of "album_tb" according to "album_id".

So I want the result as following.

[image]

How to join 2 tables?

Comment: try `FIND_IN_SET` for the same

Comment: This should demonstrate why you shouldn't store lists of id's in comma-separated strings. See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

you can use `group_concat` to concatenate album_images

```
select c1,c2,c3, group_concat(c4, ',') as album_images from 
(
  select
    ct.col1,
    ct.col2, 
    ct.col3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ct.album_id, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) albumId
  from
    (select 1 n union all
     select 2 union all select 3 union all
     select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN cart_tb ct
    on CHAR_LENGTH(ct.album_id)
       -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(ct.album_id, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
  order by
    id, n
) ct
inner join album_images ai
  on ai.rel_col = ct.rel_col
group by c1,c2,c3
```